# RxJava functional programming: how to call anonymous function with appropriate arguments

Tags: java, functional-programming, func, rx-java

RxJava's startFuture(...) takes a `Func0` (function that takes no arguments) that returns a Future.

However, I have a function that takes 3 arguments, which can be represented as `Func3<type, type, type, Future>`. I wrote this function that should close over the Func3 and return it as the result of a Func0:

```
public Func0 convertToFunc0(final Func3<type 1, type 2, type 3, Future> f)
{
    return new Func0() {
        @Override
        public void call() {
            f.call(???);
        }
    };
}
```

Assuming I have inserted the appropriate types for "type 1", "type 2" etc., how can I access the arguments of `f` so I can "close" over them? There's not really any documentation that I can find surrounding the functional parts of RxJava, and I've looked at the source but haven't gotten anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
public Func0 convertToFunc0(final Func3<type 1, type 2, type 3, Future> f, final type1 param1, final type2 param2, final type3 param3)
{
    return new Func0() {
        @Override
        public void call() {
            f.call(param1, param2, param3);
        }
    };
}
```

If `param1`, `param2` and `param3` are not thread-safe, you need to take care the potential race condition.

Comment: The parameters are definitely not thread safe. I guess this would work otherwise, but it's way too hacky, particularly since the class calling convertToFunc0 shouldn't need explicit access to the parameters.

Comment: Func3 always needs the parameters. And if you don't change the state of  the parameters, I think there is no race condition.

Comment: I ended up discussing with a colleague and he gave the same answer as you. So I guess I will accept!